# But who knew how realistic that was

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found this sentence in *The Longest Ride*:

> As scary as the prospect of real life seemed, she was excited at the thought of having her own place. She vaguely imagined a loft in some city, with bistros and coffeehouses and bars nearby, **but who knew how realistic that was**. The truth was that even living in a dumpy apartment off the highway in Omaha, Nebraska, would be preferable to her current situation. She was tired of living in the sorority house...

What is the meaning of this sentence? Actually "but who knew how realistic that was" part makes thing hard for me to understand. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It's a rhetorical question.  An answer is not expected, and the author has chosen to indicate this by using a period rather than a question mark.

Here, it indicates that "how realistic that was" was very uncertain.  She didn't know whether the scene she imagined was realistic (likely to happen) or unrealistic (unlikely to happen).  But regardless of whether that particular vision was likely to come true, she wanted to move out—anything would be better than her current situation.